# "Tomorrow might be difficult." -> Is this sentence is natural for real?

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms

I wonder the sentence "Tomorrow might be difficult." is natural.

For meaning like this context :

A : how about having dinner with me tomorrow?

B : Tomorrow might be difficult. I have to do work.

Thanks for your answer in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is an idiomatic way of saying

> It might be difficult for me to (have dinner) tomorrow.

Similarly you can say

> Tomorrow is good.

Tomorrow can function both as a noun and as an adverb.